# Repositories.getRepositoryFor() returns null in SpringBootTest

Tags: testing, spring-boot, junit

My goal is to test annotation processor. To do this I decided to create some test data with annotations in test package. My annotation processor uses Spring Repositories, but they return null every time, even if the repository exists. In debug I noticed that my repositories do not exist in applicationContext.
How can I force Spring to see my repositories?

My Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class, 
RepoConfig.class, AnnotationProcessor.class}, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AnnotationProcessorTest{

@Autowired
private AnnotationProcessor processor;

@Test
public void test(){
    assertNotNull(processor.getRepositories()); //Repositories is empty
}
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyClass, 
Serializable> {
}
```

MyClass:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private String ref;

    private String field;
}
```

RepoConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {MyRepository.class})
public class RepoConfig{
}
```

AnnotationProcessor:

```
@Component
public class AnnotationProcessor{

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext appContext;

    private Repositories repositories;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       repositories = new Repositories(appContext);

       ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
       scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Repository.class, false, false));
    scanner.findCandidateComponents("com").forEach(this::processRepository);
    }

    private void processRepository(BeanDefinition bean) {
        Class<?> repoClass = Class.forName(bean.getBeanClassName());
        Repository annotation = repoClass.getAnnotation(Repository.class);
        //TODO: processing annotation
    }

    public Repositories getRepositories(){
         return repositories;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is AnnotationProcessor?

Comment: AnnotationProcessor is a custom class that processes annotations from MyClass and generate specific metadata. There is a lot of logic there, but it crashes because could not find any repository at application context.

Comment: Please include that code.

Comment: AnnotationProcessor sample added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of a class populating the `Repositories` object.

```
@Component
public class RepositoryConfigurer {
    private Repositories repositories;

    @Autowired
    public RepositoryConfigurer(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.repositories = new Repositories(applicationContext);
    }

    public Repositories getRepositories() {
        return this.repositories;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Autowired
    RepositoryConfigurer repositoryConfigurer;

    @Test
    public void testRepositoriesConfigurer() {
        assertThat(repositoryConfigurer).isNotNull();

        Repositories repositories = repositoryConfigurer.getRepositories();
        assertThat(repositories).isNotNull();

        repositories.forEach(repository -> {
            System.out.println(repository.getName());
        });
    }
}
```

Including project for reference.  [spring-boot-tests](https://github.com/ryan2049/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-sample-tests)

Comment: I have no SpringBootApplication class in my project :(

Comment: Which version of spring-boot are you using?  Can you setup a github repo showing your project?

Comment: The issue was solved by adding SpringBootApplication class. Thank you!